# For beginners. How to add and remove widgets while the application is running in kivy python? And how to bind functionality with buttons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

For beginners. Examples and preferably explanations.

Kivy is object oriented GUI framework. Such basic things as in my question are not obvious to beginners. I think they need to be explained and shown by examples.

Comment: Wouldn't that be covered by any kivy tutorial?

Comment: The emphasis is not always placed on these places. I decided to point them to the stack overflow so that these points could be found faster by beginners. "Early successes are important." Beginners at the beginning may encounter these problems.

Comment: "Early successes are important." This advice will help beginners. These moments are not always covered. And here I want to consider them all. So that beginners can overcome this first stage faster.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class BeginnerApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.count = 0
        
        a = root.add_widget(Button(text='add button', on_press=self.add_button))
        
        b = root.add_widget(Button(text='remove button', on_press=self.delete_button))
        
        return root
        
    
    def add_button(self, *args):
        self.count += 1
        self.root.add_widget(Button(text=str(self.count)))
    
    def delete_button(self, *args):
        if self.count > 0:
            self.root.remove_widget(self.root.children[0])
            self.count -= 1
        else:
            pass
        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = BeginnerApp()
    app.run()
```

This is an example without kv language.

Note 1: when you bind a method, specify its name without brackets. Otherwise, binding does not work normally.

```py
on_press=self.add_button
on_press=self.delete_button
```

Note 2: to add widgets in layout you can use method "add_widget()".

```py
self.root.add_widget(Button())
```

For delete widget you can use method "remove_widget()". To delete a widget in layout, you need to specify this widget. This can be done through the "children" method. The last widget in the "children" method is numbered "0". So you can delete the last widget in layout.

```py
self.root.remove_widget(self.root.children[0])
```

Note 3: When declaring methods, don't forget *args.

```py
def add_button(self, *args):
```